# Options instead of Get Request when adding custom headers

Tags: react-admin

When I try out the below code to add token to my header. My get request is not called but the options is called. This makes it unable to populate the listview in react-admin. Any advice on how to resolved this ?

````
import { fetchUtils, Admin, Resource } from 'react-admin';
import simpleRestProvider from 'ra-data-simple-rest';

const httpClient = (url, options = {}) => {
    if (!options.headers) {
        options.headers = new Headers({ Accept: 'application/json' });
    }
    const token = localStorage.getItem('token');
    options.headers.set('Authorization', `Bearer ${token}`);
    return fetchUtils.fetchJson(url, options);
};
const dataProvider = simpleRestProvider('http://localhost:3000', httpClient);

const App = () => (
    <Admin dataProvider={dataProvider} authProvider={authProvider}>
        ...
    </Admin>
); ```
````

Comment: Your browser checks that the server allows cross-origin AJAX calls. This is totally normal if the API and the web page are on different domains. You need to update your API to include CORS headers - see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS for details.